# Find a subset of $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ isomorphic to $Exp(\omega, \omega)$ as well ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

I have tried to find an isomorphism $\phi$ in this way:
Let $f \in \operatorname{Exp}(\omega, \omega)$ and let the $k$ pairs $(n_i,f(n_i))$ such that for every $0<i<k+1$, $f(n_i)\ne 0$.
I'd like to close $\phi(f)$  between $n_k$ and $n_k +1$.
For example, if exist an only pairs with $f(n)\not=0$, $\phi(f)=n+1-
 \frac{1}{f(n)}$. I think it's possible to build $ \phi $ for countable recursion but I can not figure out how.

Comment: What is Exp????

Comment: @WilliamElliot $\omega^\omega$ as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation) e.g.

Comment: @WilliamElliot This is a countable ordinal and as such must be order isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. The OP wants an explicit such isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the best I could find.

The idea is to construct the images $S_n:=\text{Im}\left(\phi|_{[0,\omega^n]}\right)$ recursively, so that:

- $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1)=1$;
- for any $n \ge 0$, if $\phi(\omega^n)=a_n$ (so that $S_n \setminus \{ a_n \}=\text{Im}(\phi) \cap [0,a_n)$ is isomorphic to $\omega^n$), the set $S_{n+1}$ is obtained by concatenating $\omega$ "rescaled copies" of $S_n \setminus \{ a_n \}$, each of which is contained in an interval of the form $\left[2a_n(1-2^{-k}),2a_n(1-2^{-k-1})\right]$, and finally $\phi(\omega^{n+1})=2a_n=a_{n+1}$.

This actually satisfies $\phi(f)\in [2^{n_k},2^{n_k+1}]$ (with the same notation you used), but it should have some other nice properties, like the following (I didn't prove all of them, but I strongly believe all of them to be true):

- $\phi(\omega^n)=2^n$;
- $\phi(\omega \cdot \alpha)=2 \phi(\alpha)$;
- $\phi$ is limit-preserving;
- if $\alpha=\omega^{n_1}+\omega^{n_2}+...+\omega^{n_r}$ with $n_1 \ge n_2 \ge ... \ge n_r$, then $\phi(\alpha)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^r 2^{n_i+1-i}$.